Анализ *.lib файлов в Ghidra
Доброго времени суток.
Потребовалось собрать старый проект из исходников и внести в них небольшие изменения.
Проект довольно большой и разбит на exe + несколько библиотек.
Выяснилось что имеющиеся исходники не соответствуют скомпилированным библиотекам, а правки нужно внести в одну из них.
Что сейчас есть:

устаревшие исходники библиотек
актуальные хедеры + *.lib + *.pdb собранных в Release/Debug библиотек

Что нужно:

обновить исходники одной из библиотек до версии в *.lib

Собственно вопрос:
Можно ли как то загрузить в Ghidra заголовочные файлы и PDB?
UPD0: есть возможность загрузить PDB для *.exe / *.dll, но не для *.lib
